# Magento 2 : Add To Cart Product Ajax Success is Can't Working On Home Page

Tags: magento2, product, ajaxaddtocart

we have one issue about some add to cart product ajax success working
in all page but homepage when adding to cart product then can't working.

Home page ajax success can't be working in Magento 2
so please tell me guys how can I sort this issue.
please give suggestion ASAP

Thank you.